# Pyodbc timeout while connecting to SQL Server on Linux

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, windows, vpn

During connection (not query execution), following problem with timeout occurs:

```
('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Code:

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
DF = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
```

This problem doesn't exist on Windows. In both cases I am using Forticlient VPN. Other networking works fine. Current configuration: Ubuntu 20.04 current patch, Windows 10 current patch. Driver was installed with official Microsoft's instruction:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Firewall issue? Can you telnet to the Server-IP:Server-Port?

Comment: After inspection pinging the server seems to work, but i cannot use telnet, with server refusing connection. What how can this be solved? It's exactly same PC, end it was not added to whitelist on firewall side.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I am also stuck at the same error and also using FortiClient on Mac.